# Fitting a quadratic through 5 points, goal is to find the maximum

Tags: curve-fitting

I have some physical experiments done at various locations. The locations produces a set of observations y for one value of x, the independent variable. In the end across a set of locations I have values in the following form

[y11, y21, y31, y41, y51, y61...] for one value of x, say x1

Then I repeat the experiment and get a new set of values

[y21, y22, y32, y42, y52, y62...] for a different value of x say x2

Ans so on.

In the end I have readings for y for 5 distinct values of x, [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]

I wish to fit a quadratic to this data, and my main goal is to find the value of x, for which y is maximum. One way to do this is to define an average y for each x1 and fit a quadratic with the averaged out values. I know that fitting a quadratic to just 5 points is not a good idea. I am open to other ideas, that can help me solve the problem without directly fitting a functional relationship.

Some non-parametric idea for instance. One idea I have is to do some distribution analysis on values of y for x1, vs values of y for x2 and so on. This enables me to take all the y values for one x1, without averaging them. I would be open to other ideas and suggestions.

Comment: "without directly fitting a functional relationship" - why don't you want to fit this? (I assume you have good reasons for suspecting a quadratic relationship, right?)

Comment: Yes, I do. Well, primarily because I think 5 points is too little to infer the curvature and the slope etc. I guess what I mean to say is to find out a way to "not loose" the information by virtue of averaging the values of y, while fitting the quadratic.

Comment: What causes variation in the measurment x *within* each location? Is it measurment error or somethong else?

Comment: Locational effects primarily plus yes some measurement error.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that inferring a parabola from five points is too little data. But you have more than five points, namely all your measurements! Don't do any averaging (though this would already help), just fit the parabola to *all* your data. Model fitting doesn't mind multiple `x` values.

Let's do this in R. Some dummy data over five different `x` values:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- rep(1:5,each=10)
yy <- -xx^2+6*xx-5+rnorm(length(xx),0,1)
```

Now we can fit the model. Note the `I()` to protect your square term, and note that this really presupposes homoskedastic errors:

```
model <- lm(yy~xx+I(xx^2))
```

Now we have a quadratic relationship. Some elementary calculus gives us the (estimated) `x` coordinate of maximum of the fitted parabola:

```
xx.max <- -coef(model)[2]/(2*coef(model)[3])
```

It's always a good idea to get an idea about the *variability* of our results. It may be possibly to derive a confidence interval for `xx.max` analytically, but the bootstrap is always easier, and given enough data (50 points should be enough), it should be valid:

```
require(boot)
foo <- boot(data=data.frame(xx=xx,yy=yy),statistic=function(data,indices){
        model <- lm(yy~xx+I(xx^2),data[indices,])
        -coef(model)[2]/(2*coef(model)[3])},
    strata=xx,
    R=1000)
```

Note that I am doing a *stratified bootstrap*, i.e., I am sampling with replacement *within each `x` value*, which makes sense here, since the data really are stratified.

So we can plot our points, the fitted parabola and the `x` coordinate of the estimated maximum together with the bootstrapped confidence interval:

```
plot(xx,yy,pch=19)
rect(quantile(foo$t,0.025),-2,quantile(foo$t,0.975),6,border=NA,col="lightgrey")
points(xx,yy,pch=19)
xx.plot <- seq(1,5,by=.01)
lines(xx.plot,predict(model,newdata=data.frame(xx=xx.plot)))
abline(v=xx.max)
```

[image: parabola]

Comment: This is interesting, never thought like this though I know this can be done. What advantages (statistical) does this have over just averaging the data?

Comment: Truth be told, averaging probably gives you pretty similar results. One difference is that here, every point has the same impact on the result - if you average first and the groups have different sizes, then a point in a small group will have a larger impact on the end result than a point in a big group.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a bootstrapped confidence interval. This works fine for my toy data but may blow up if your estimated leading coefficient is close to zero. But try it! No estimate should come without a measure of its variability!

Comment: Thanks Stephan, how about this. For the bootstrap, I randomly sample one y for each of x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, i.e from the respective distributions. So in the end I have tuples of points (xi,yi), where i is 1 to 5. Note y1, is a random sample from the distribution [y11, y12, y13, ....]. I do this howsoever times I want, fit the quadratic, find the maxima. And then use this to find the confidence.

Comment: That is also a possibility. It will essentially simulate having only one `y` per `x`, though, "forgetting" that you really have many more data points. It will thus overestimate the variance for the max estimate. Alternatively, do a *stratified bootstrap*, sampling with replacement *within each `x` coordinate*. That would probably be more appropriate for your data, anyway. Let me edit the question to stratify. (Not that it makes a big difference, anyways.)

Comment: When I meant randomly sample one y, I really meant a uniform random sampling with replacement. Is that what you call a stratified boostrap? What is your other comment on overestimating the variance? When would the variance be overestimated and why?

Comment: In the stratified bootstrap, you don't sample *one* `y` over each `x`, but multiple ones (with replacement). With my toy data, I have 10 `y` over each `x`. So the stratified bootstrap would sample 10 times from the `y` vector over each `x` (with replacement). So you again have 50 data points to fit the model. The result is that the parameter estimates (and the estimate for the `x` coordinate of the maximum) will have a lower variance than if you only sample one `y` over each `x`. (You may want to read up on the [bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29).)

Comment: I see that, thanks much, this is good. I did read the wiki article, but that doesn't talk about the stratified technique. So my understanding is that it basically entails sampling the entire vector of y values for each x and fitting the models repeatedly. Is there a good resource for reading more into it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20196/discussion-between-ganesh-reddy-and-stephan-kolassa).